# Autostart of the xserver at boot up when the monitor is unplugged

Tags: xorg, vnc, xubuntu

I was running Xubuntu 8.04 "Hardy Heron".   I configure the vnc by adding vino-server to the autostarted app.  I accessing the display only via VNC, so I removed the monitor and ir worked fine.

When I upgrade to 10.04 "Lucid Lynx", I was unable to connect.  I borrow back the monitor and I plug it.  I was seeing nothing so I do a restart by ssh.  When it restart, I was able to vnc without an issue.  I removed the monitor and worked like that for a few week, but when I installed some update, I needed to restart.  After the restart, the vnc is not available.  When I to a ps -aux by ssh, the xserver does not seem to be running.

How could I tell xubuntu 10.04 to automatically start the xserver when no monitor is plug, just as 8.04?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, it tries to start X, and fail.  With the original xorg.conf, I got the following error message in xconf.o.log : Segmentation fault at address 0x24

Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting

Comment: Since I got a seg fault, I filled a bug for it : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/660931

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace xorg.conf in /etc/X11 by the file in : http://ubuntu-virginia.ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9565510&postcount=25

Edit /boot/grub/menu.lst to add " nomodeset" to the line beginning with "# kopt=", then run sudo update-grub.  The # should stay at the beginning of the line.  (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes#Working%20around%20bugs%20in%20the%20new%20kernel%20video%20architecture)

Thanks to JanC for it's help.  If I could, I would edit it's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might try the following solution: http://ubuntu-virginia.ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9565510&postcount=25

It might also be useful to use another driver instead of 'vesa' in the config (but OTOH, when used with VNC you have no real hardware acceleration anyway) or to change the resolution if you prefer that.

If you don't have an /etc/default/grub file, you're probably still using "legacy" grub (aka "grub 1"). In that case you will have to edit /boot/grub/menu.lst and change the line starting with "# defoptions=" to include nomodeset.

After adding nomodeset to any of those files, you should also run `sudo update-grub` (I see that's not mentioned in that forum post).

Comment: This solution is about "10.04 won't boot".  In my case, it is booting, it's just not starting X.

Comment: I don't have a file called /etc/default/grub

Comment: I already have xorg.conf in /etc/X11, here what it contains : Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier      "Default Layout"
        Screen          "Default Screen"
EndSection

Comment: @Guillaume: it's also about X not starting.  And if you don't have that file, you're probably still using "legacy" grub (aka "grub 1").  In that case you will have to edit /boot/grub/menu.lst and change the line starting with "# defoptions=".

Comment: And you can edit the existing xorg.conf

Comment: The proposed xorg.conf doesn't work either.   I just get a different error message : (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
(II) Primary Device is: PCI 00@00:0d:0
(EE) VESA: Kernel modesetting driver in use, refusing to load
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
(EE) No devices detected.

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Comment: That's because the 'nomodeset' boot parameter is not working.  I just see an important part is missing from that forum post, I'll add a comment about that to my answer...

Comment: Do you know where that 'nomodeset' boot parameter is documented?  I am a little unsecure about modifying boot parameters without first reading carefully the documentation.  I did man grub, but there was nothing on it.

Comment: It's documented in the ["Lucid" (10.04) release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes#Working%20around%20bugs%20in%20the%20new%20kernel%20video%20architecture).

Comment: However, when I run sudo update-grub, it output : Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst.  And the update menu.lst does not contains the option.  I reboot twice, with boot the old and the suggested configuration and I got the same error in both case.  I think the modification to menu.lst is ignored by update-grub.

Comment: It's kopt, not defoptions